# Does Unzip algorithm runs over whole compressed data? or over certain number of bytes?

Tags: zip, unzip

I have to unzip a file which is being downloaded from a server. I have gone through the zip file structure. What I want to understand is, if compressed data is constructed using how many bytes of a data bytes? Is the compression algorithm runs over all the file and generates output or compression algorithm runs on let's say 256 bytes, output result, and select next 256 bytes.

Similarly, do I need to download the whole file before running uncompressing algorithm? or I can download 256 bytes ( for example) and run the algorithm on it?

Comment: I have to perform unzip operation on Cortex M4 controller and have memory constraints.

Comment: Also, I do not have file system implemented. All data is stored in dataflash, so will ziplib or minizip libraries work still?